# Problem with IF condition and && OPERATOR

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, max, palindrome

i have encountered a major problem in my code that, when i hits 1 and j is 5, although, the boolean function returns False, the IF statement still manage to operate.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool checkSym(string s, int left, int right) {
  if (left >= right)
    return true;
  else {
    if (int(s[left]) != int(s[right]))
      return false;
    else {
      checkSym(s, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  // TODO
  string s, c, d;
  s = "babadad";
  int max = 0;
  int n = s.length();
  for (int i = 0; n - i >= max; i++) {
    c = "";
    for (int j = max; j <= n - i; j++) {
      c = s.substr(i, j);
      if (checkSym(c, 0, j - 1) && j > max) {
        max = j;
        d = c;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << d;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated: Don't do stuff like `string s, c, d;` to yourself. The time saved typing 1 letter identifiers will almost always be swallowed up, along several large bites out of the surrounding time, by the time spent debugging the resultant hard-to-read code.

Comment: I guess, it is hitting the `if condition` maybe due the `max` value being lower than the `j` value.

Comment: Always compile C++ with `-Wall`. It'll warn you about likely mistakes like this and save a *ton* of trouble.

Comment: Either turn on warnings on your compiler or actually read the warnings

Comment: I highly recommend placing the return value from `checkSym` into a `const` temporary variable before the `if` statement.  This allows you to place a breakpoint at the `if` statement and see the return value from `checkSym`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks unreadable. Nevertheless at least this function

```
bool checkSym(string s, int left, int right) {
  if (left >= right)
    return true;
  else {
    if (int(s[left]) != int(s[right]))
      return false;
    else {
      checkSym(s, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because it returns nothing in this code snippet

```
    else {
      checkSym(s, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
```

You need to write

```
    else {
      return checkSym(s, left + 1, right - 1);
    }
```

Also it is unclear why there is used explicit casting to the type `int`

```
 if (int(s[left]) != int(s[right]))
```

instead of just writing

```
 if ( s[left] != s[right])
```

Comment: The return one really helps, thanks for your supportttt !!!